# Taking the expectation of a probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, independence

I am trying to understand what it means to have an expectation of a probability density function taken over a *different, independent* random variable.

Let's say I have a random variable $X$ with density $f_X$ and support $\mathcal{X}$ and an independent random variable $Y$ with density $g_Y$ and support $\mathcal{Y}$. Then what does $$\mathbb{E}_{X}[g_Y(x)]$$ mean?

Does this mean $$\int_{\mathcal{X}} g_Y(x) f_X(x) dx$$
**And if so, can the integrand be simplified since $X$ and $Y$ are independent?**

Comment: You have a small misunderstanding of the notation and the concept of expectation. The notation $$\mathbb{E}_{X}[g_Y(x)]$$ means that you are taking the expectation of the function $g_Y(x)$ with respect to the random variable $X$, not $Y$. Since $g_Y(x)$ is the density function of the random variable $Y$, this notation might seem confusing.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding. I mean to say that the function $g_Y$ is the pdf of random variable $Y$, but I intend to take the expectation of $g_Y$ over random variable $X$. I am purposefully mixing the random variables, but I may not be writing it correctly.

Comment: Perhaps it would make more sense if I wrote it as $$\mathbb{E}_{X}[p(Y = x)]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem** Let $u$ be a measurable function and $x$ a random variable with distribution $F.$ Then $\mathbf{E}(u(x)) = \int\limits_\mathbf{R} u(t) dF(t);$ if $F$ has a density $f,$ so that "$dF(t) = f(t) dt$", then $\mathbf{E}(u(x)) = \int\limits_\mathbf{R} u(t) f(t) dt.$

You now apply this theorem when $u = g_Y.$ Whether $u$ has additional meaning is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be really explicit, do you mean independence doesn't really affect anything here?

Comment: Independence affects products, so if you had $\mathbf{E}(u(x) v(y))$ then independence allows to write this as $\mathbf{E}(u(x)) \mathbf{E}(v(y)).$ What are $u$ and $v$ is really irrelevant, they are just assumed measurable functions (and they can be measurable functions intimately connected between them or to a third variable).

Comment: @MrBear you might be confused with conditional expectation where $\mathbf{E}(u(x) \mid y)$ will depend on $y$ and $x$ (and will be independent, i.e., free of $y,$ if $(x,y)$ is stochastically independent).